# Calculate a Reference Date in DAX

Tags: date, dax

Trying to nail down the syntax for a pretty straightforward problem.

I have a table called `Events` and a full-feature `DATES` table with a relationship between the `Dates[Date]` field.

Using the `event name` as a slicer, I trying to create a `[First Monday]` measure that will return the date of the first Monday of the month.

So for example, if my event date was **2/14/19**, `[First Monday]` would return **2/4/19**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Date table needs to contain 2 columns:

- Year-Month: for example, "2018-01"
- Weekday Number: for example, 1 (for Monday); or Weekday Name (i.e, "Monday")

Then:

```
First Monday = 
  CALCULATE( MIN('Date'[Date]),
             ALL('Date'),
             VALUES('Date'[Year-Month]),
            'Date'[Weekday Name] = "Monday")
```

How it works:

First, we need to access all dates in the Date table, so we use ALL()

Second, we need to see only dates for the current context year and month, for which we can use VALUES()

Third, for each month we only want Mondays, hence Date[Weekday] = "Monday"

All this unfiltering/filtering generates a set of Mondays for the Year-Month visible in the current filter context. All we need to do now is to find the earliest of the Mondays using Min(Date).